# Javascript: How to dynamicly add a number to a variable name?

Tags: javascript

Say I have to following code:

```
var numb = $(selector).length;
```

And now I want to dynamicly make variables based on this:

```
var temp+numb = ...
```

How would I be able to do this?

Edit:

I know some of you will tell me to use an array. Normally I would agree but in my case the var is already an array and I rly see no other solution than creating dynamic names.

Comment: here it is:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/javascript-dynamic-variable-name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Variables in Javascript are bound to objects. Objects accept both `.` and `[]` notation. So you could do:

```
var num = 3;    
window["foo"+num] = "foobar";    
console.log(foo3);
```

*PS - Just because you can do that doesn't mean you should, though.*

Comment: Only works in a browser window, not server-side, and really messy.

Comment: @deitch - hence my suggestion of a scope of his own

Comment: @deitch: Hence the disclaimer at the end of the question. It's hard to offer a better solution (and I'm sure there is one) unless OP shares more context.

Comment: I just need it client side. It's for a socketserver chatsystem and I want to use this to dynamicly open tabs for private chats. This is what I needed to get it done. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In global scope (not recommended):

```
window["temp"+numb]='somevalue;
window.console && console.log(temp3);
```

In a scope you create - also works serverside where there is no window scope

```
var myScope={};
myScope["temp"+numb]="someValue";
window.console && console.log(myScope.temp3);
```